Question about Integrals Involving Periodic Even Functions and Trigonometric Products
In my memory, I once encountered a problem like this:

Let $f(x)$ be an even function with period $2\pi$. Show that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)\cos x\, dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\left(x\right)\cos x\, dx$$

Calculate the following integral:...


However, I couldn't recall an example where the integrals involved would yield non-zero results and remain integrable. I'm uncertain if my recollection of the first problem is correct. Has anyone seen a similar problem or has any interesting examples for this type of question?
By the way I encountered this problem in my university entrance exam, so it shouldn't be too difficult.

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)\cos x\, dx\neq 0$ but this is still too boring.
What I am looking for is something like $f(x)=\frac{1}{2+\cos x}$, not piecewise-defined, and not polynomial of $\cos x$.

Yes, or a similar problem with an interesting and non-zero example

$f(x)=x^{2k}$ for $k\in \Bbb N$ for example

Thanks for the example. However, $f(x)$ need to be periodic. A piecewise periodic function feels a bit too cumbersome. I'm looking for something more elegant, like $1/(2+\cos x)$, which however is not integrable.

if you're computing the integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$, why is it relevant what happens outside the interval of integration?

The reason it matters is because the left-hand side of the equation involves $f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)$

$f$ is $2\pi$ periodic though

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
